# mysql perform same calculation for all rows on another table

Tags: mysql

I have my query determined:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `participation` 
LEFT JOIN parties ON parties.id = participation.party_id
WHERE  `riding_id` = 10001
AND  `election_id` = 41
ORDER BY num_votes DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This accurately produces the result I want.

The result is the most voted for party.

---

Now I want to perform this same query on every row of a TABLE **ridings** 
which contains all the `riding_id` rows. Having some trouble getting it.

I don't want to join the other table - but go through every row and perform the same calculation as above - on each row.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  `participation` 
    LEFT JOIN parties ON parties.id = participation.party_id
    WHERE  `riding_id` = "LOOP ALL riding_id IN ridings TABLE"
    AND  `election_id` = 41
    ORDER BY num_votes DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to just use a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  participation LEFT JOIN
      parties
      ON parties.id = participation.party_id
WHERE  riding_id IN (SELECT riding_id FROM ridings) AND
       election_id = 41
ORDER BY num_votes DESC
```

But, you no longer get the top vote getter.  You get everything.

Here is a method using variables to get just the top vote getting for each `riding_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             (@rn := if(@r = riding_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@rn := riding_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM  participation LEFT JOIN
            parties
            ON parties.id = participation.party_id CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @rn := 0, @r := -1) params
      WHERE  riding_id IN (SELECT riding_id FROM ridings) AND
             election_id = 41
      ORDER BY riding_id, num_votes DESC 
     ) pp
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - On the second query - I get the error "Duplicate column name 'id'" Yet I only see reference to "id" once?

Comment: @Kreeverp . . . That is because of the `select *`.  You should actually list only the columns you want.